# Setting Java value

Tags: java

I am new to this, I have this:

```
public Builder id (String val)
{
    id = val;
    return this;
}
```

from below if statement i want to  set builder id = 1ac. How can I do that. Thank you

```
if (blah blah)
{
    id = "1ac";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
if(someCondition) builder.id("1ac");
```

The `id` method is written so that you pass it the value you want to set and then it returns `this` so you can chain calls together to set different values with a single statement.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for something more like this:

```
String idNew;    

public Builder id( String val )     
{             
  idNew = val;
  return idNew;     
} 

if(blah blah)
{
  id("1ac");
}
```

Or, of course, what the guy above me said.  Either or.

Comment: You are returning a String when the method is meant to return a Builder.